# JavaFX KeyEvent - Is it possible to get more info for Undefined Events?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to register global hotkeys directly with the operating system for my program. I have it working for all keys that are listed as a JavaFX KeyCode, but if the KeyCode is "Undefined" for a particular key, I am not able to distinguish it from other undefined keys, so I can't use it.

**OS**: xubuntu 18.04.  
**Java**: Version 11.0.1 2018-10-16 LTS, Oracle 
**JavaFX**: SDK 11.0.1

A good example are the "Media Keys" that are located on many keyboards.
When I press a media key on my keyboard, I get an undefined KeyEvent:

> **System.out.println(keyEvent)**: Key Event: KeyEvent [source = TextField@25181b05[styleClass=text-input text-field], target = TextField@25181b05[styleClass=text-input text-field], eventType = KEY_PRESSED, consumed = true, character =
>
> **keyEvent.getCode()**: UNDEFINED

**I would like to be able to recognize if that key is pressed again**. I don't need to know what the name of the key is. I just need to know the next time that unique key is pressed and react.

The problem is that I don't see any way to differentiate between UNDEFINED keys in KeyEvent in JavaFX. Based on the public API of KeyEvent and by looking at the source code of KeyEvent in JavaFX, it seems like KeyEvent does not keep any additional information that can uniquely identify a key press that is Undefined in KeyCode.

Digging deeper into the JavaFX code, it appears the unique identifier I need *might* be present in the method `EmbeddedScene.keyEvent`:

```
@Override
public void keyEvent(final int type, final int key, final char[] ch, final int modifiers);
```

That argument `final int key` is passed to a `KeyCodeMap.valueOf (key)`  function, which, in this case, returns KeyCode.UNDEFINED.  I can't easily test, but I'd bet that that `int` has different values for each of these different media keys.

is there any way to listen for KeyEvents at a lower level on a JavaFX stage -- before they get converted into a KeyCode and the information I need is lost -- so I can catch the hotkey and register it with the operating system?

I'm confident that if I can just get a method in my code base to fire when a key is pressed, and have that key show a unique identifer, I can wire the rest of the parts together. It doesn't necessarily need to be in the JavaFX stack.

Comment: I can't really answer your question, but in my opinion, you can't do it in pure Java. My suggestion would be to use a library written in C ( or any other low-level language). A well known is [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook)

Comment: Yes, I just looked at this at the "glass" level (which is probably the lowest layer you can get in JavaFX). `com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._getKeyCodeForChar(char)` is defined as `protected native int _getKeyCodeForChar(char c);`. Seems like you definitely need to do it from the native layer, which requires low-level API.

Comment: A simple JNI library that listens for key events and gets the X11 keysym and sends it up to my program might do the trick. Good idea. Although I'm a little hesitant to write and use a library that listen in to all key events, even if they're immediately discarded.